# Story ident : Lesbian space trader

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for the title and author of a non-series book which was written by a woman in the 1980s. The details of the book are:

- The main character is a female trader dealing with smugglers
- She's a lesbian or bisexual
- The story is set on a non-earth planet
- The lead character becomes involved with a female smuggler
- The secondary character is a male net runner who collects info for her
- Ultimately the female smuggler is killed

The author has also written several fantasy novels. The Book was most likely published by small press.  **What is the name of this book?**

Comment: Hi Welcome to [SFF.SE!](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) Could you help by adding a more descriptive and 'searchable' title please?

Comment: @Mooz - Edited to be a bit more visible as a story ident question.

Answer (score 8):

The book is Mainline by Deborah Christian.  I was way off on the date of publication -- it's 1997.

Answer (score 4):

It could be ***[Friends in High Places](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1934452084)*** by Andi Marquette.

**Why it fits:**

- Written by a woman ([Andi Marquette](http://andimarquette.com/))
- About an outlaw female space smuggler (I believe is gay)
- Two lead characters

  - One male - Kai Tinsdale (the Captain for the "coalition")
  - One female - Torri Rendego (the smuggler)
- Kai collects information for Torri (she has to decide whether she trusts him or not)

**Why it doesn't fit:**

- Published in 2007 (not 1980's)
- Story is set in "Old-Earth" (not a non-Earth planet)
- It *is* a series book ([book one of three](http://andimarquette.com/books/far-seek-chronicles/))

Comment: No, that's not it but thanks for replying.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck!