# Story with a woman trader who speaks all known languages and is seeking interstellar trading rights

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am looking for a story with a woman trader who speaks all known languages, and she travels in a ship with a computer that has developed sentience.  She travels to a newly discovered planet inhabited by a race of beings sporting feather-like crests to learn their language so that trade/mining rights may be entered into.

This is a novel length story that is at least 20, if not more, years old.

Comment: Any of these?http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73805/story-ident-lesbian-space-trader

Comment: or these; http://www.tinahunter.ca/2009/female-leads-in-science-fiction-novels/

Comment: These are all excellent stories but they are not the one I am searching for.  Thank you for helping Richard!

Comment: [Someone else was asking](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85268/story-identification-linguist-ambassador-between-planets) for a story about a woman linguist in space. Any chance it's the same story?

Answer (score 1):

*[Forest of the Night](http://www.fantasticfiction.co.uk/s/marti-steussy/forest-of-night.htm)* and *Dreams of Dawn* by Marti Steussy feature feathered tigers and a linguist, if I remember correctly. Also horses.

> The First-In team had promised New Lebanon's loggers that the planet's tigerlike predators were gone. But it was a tiger that stood over Hashti in the woods, pawing her and uttering an eerie, songlike cry. Panicked, the horse trainer hit her assailant. He snorted in surprise--and fled. The tiger's call haunted Hashti. The First-Inners heard mystery in the alien song. The loggers heard danger. Hashti's lover heard profit--and the loggers agreed. The unusual feathered tiger pelts represented a way to buy themselves out of lifelong debt to Oldearth Company. But Hashti and the First-Inners had begun to believe that the tigers might be intelligent beings. Someone had to learn the truth before the colonists' terror led to wide-scale massacre. So Hashti set out into the forest alone to learn the ways of the tigers...

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me of [A Thousand Words for Stranger](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0756404584) by Julie Czerneda. This is the first book in what is now [two trilogies](https://www.czerneda.com/sf/thousand.html). She is a trader, has to find someone with a ship to flee. You may have the "speaks all languages" confused with telepathy, which the main character has.

> Sira is on the run. The mysterious Captain Morgan has a starship. But if she goes with him, who will be at risk? Meet the Clan, shadowy figures of unfathomable power. Meet Huido, the lobster-like restauranteur. Meet the Trade Pact Enforcers, who have their own intentions. For events are beginning to unfold that will affect them all.
>
> <sup>[Goodreads, A Thousand Words for Stranger (Trade Pact Universe #1)](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/129019.A_Thousand_Words_for_Stranger)</sup>